# changing default hierarchy of Cube dimension

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssas, cubes, cube-dimension

I have created Dealer dimension in SSAS 2005 and it has 3 hierarchies. By default the hierarchy created first is the default hierarchy of the dimension.
Is there any way to change the default hierarchy to another hierarchy.

Comment: is deleting all the hierarchies and create the default hierarchy first is the only way ..?

Answer (score 2):

In Business Intelligence Development Studio, if you open the Dimension, you can drag the Hierarchies to change their order. The first Hierarchy in the list is the default.

(Note that this takes effect as soon as you save - you don't need to reprocess anything).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is actually a "default hierarchy" property, but if you want to change the ordering of the hierarchies you could try scripting out the dimension as "Alter" from SQL Management Studio and then changing the order of the  nodes.